# Test Harness asks for input rather than using what is written(homework)

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to use a test harness for homework to check if a module works. I've only done 2 tests so far, but when I debug the program, it asks me for an input rather than using what I've provided in the code. What did I do wrong?

```
void retirement_eligibility(bool full_time, int age, int service_years, bool &eligibility);

using namespace std;

int main()

{
     bool full_time,
          eligibility;

     int  age,
          service_years,
          contribution;


     full_time = 0;
     eligibility = 0;
     service_years = 0;
     age = 0;



     retirement_eligibility(1, 30, 1, eligibility);
     if (eligibility == true){
          cout << "Test 1 passed" << endl;
     }
     else {
          cout << "Test #1 FAILED!" << endl;
          cout << " - Expected eligibility 1, got" << eligibility << endl;

     }
     retirement_eligibility(1, 29, 1, eligibility);
     if (eligibility == 2){
          cout << "Test 2 passed" << endl;
     }
     else {
          cout << "Test #2 FAILED!" << endl;
          cout << " - Expected eligibility 2, got" << eligibility << endl;

     }
}

void retirement_eligibility(bool full_time, int age, int service_years, bool &eligibility)
{

     cout << "Enter age: ";
     cin >> age;
     cout << "Enter years served: ";
     cin >> service_years;
     cout << "Are you a full time eployee?(1 for yes, 2 for no): ";
     cin >> full_time;

     if (full_time == true){
          if (age >= 30 && service_years >= 1){
               eligibility = true;
          }

          else{
               eligibility = false;
          }
     }

     else{
          eligibility = false;
     }

}
```

Comment: Are you adding tests or using a test framework?

Comment: I need to add more, but what my teacher is expecting in the output is ""Test 1 passed"
"Test 2 passed"

instead of
"Enter age: "
"Enter years served: " "Are you a full time eployee?(1 for yes, 2 for no): " "Test 1 passed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void retirement_eligibility(bool full_time, int age, int service_years, bool &eligibility)
{
    cout << "Enter age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Enter years served: ";
    cin >> service_years;
    cout << "Are you a full time eployee?(1 for yes, 2 for no): ";
    cin >> full_time;

    ...
}
```

It asks for input because you ask for input in your function. It doesn't matter what you pass to it because you are changing it with the inputs you ask for in the function itself.